# Accessing object property when object consists of classes

Tags: typescript, types

With an object consisting of references to classes:

```
// commands/index.ts
export default {
  Authorize,
  BootNotification,
  ...
  UpdateFirmware,
};
```

How do I go about creating variables and instantiate dynamically from this object?
For something like below I get the ts error:

```
TS2538: Type '{ Authorize: typeof Authorize; BootNotification: typeof BootNotification; CancelReservation: typeof CancelReservation; ChangeAvailability: typeof ChangeAvailability; ... 23 more ...; UpdateFirmware: typeof UpdateFirmware; }' cannot be used as an index type.
```

Code:

```
import commands from "./commands"; 
let commandNameOrPayload: typeof commands;
let commandPayload: any;
let CommandModel: typeof commands;

CommandModel = commands[commandNameOrPayload];
commandRequest = new CommandModel(commandPayload);
```

For the last line of `newCommandModel` I'm getting the error: `TS2351: This expression is not constructable.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes from your `commands` export are indexed by the string representation of their name, so in order to access them, your `commandNameOrPayload` also needs to be of type `string`:

```js
class A {/**bla**/}

class B {/**bla**/}

let commands = {
  A,
  B
}

console.log(commands["A"]) // will log class A {}
let command = new commands["A"];

console.log(command instanceof A)
```

See my playground: https://tsplay.dev/wjkrbN

Comment: So turn `commandNameOrPayload` into an enumerate and leave ` CommandModel`  as type of any? Then typescript should be able to infer the type automatically? It seems to work without any errors.

Comment: Yeah, commandNameOrPayload needs to be a string, CommandModel should be `any`